# Get Value From MySQL Table, Multiply It and Store it Again

Tags: php, mysql

I'm newbie and need help about PHP MySQL:

I have a Table in MySQL like this:

Number1 | Number2 | Calculate  |
   8                |   9                  |                           |
   5                |   6                  |                          |
   3                |   2                  |                           |

With PHP, how to get Number1 and Number2 values, multiply each row and store it to Calculate column?

Here is my code:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Multiply");
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)); {
    $Num1=$result['Number1']; $Num2=$result['Number2'];
    $result=$Num1+Num2;
    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Multiply SET calculate=$result");
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You forgot a dollar sign in this line: ```$result=$Num1+$Num2;``` -- What error messages do you get? Looks fine to me otherwise.

Comment: Why store the result in the `Calculate` column?  It is redundant information and (absent a trigger that enforces the constraint) risks becoming desynchronised.  Why not calculate it upon retrieval, e.g. within the `SELECT` command?

Comment: I think that, if you want to multiply, doing `$result = $Num1 + $Num2;` might give some hints of what's wrong...

Comment: Here is the error:Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in D:\xampp-portable\htdocs\aritmatika\testing.php on line 7

Comment: @user3099626: You are mixing `ext/mysql` with MySQLi`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
$result=$Num1*Num2;
```

to

```
$result=$Num1*$Num2;
```

or just run the below sql

```
"UPDATE Multiply SET Calculate = Number1 * Number2"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
$query = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Multiply SET Calculate = Number1 * Number2");
```

Answer (score 1):

you don'T even need to go through php, or you can just call the query from php as

```
update Multiply set calculate=number1*number2
```